# Lighting problem

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am learning Blender 2.80    I am trying to set up lighting for a car I'm working on...  I have tried the lighting with sun, with planes as lighting set to Emission, with area lights.   I changed the settings in World to different ones,  For some reason parts of the car (door, hood)  don't show the color...
    I never had any issues when doing the lighting in Blender 2.79B   but this 2.80 is giving much headache trying to get the lighting to work when I am doing a car   This image is using the Area lights...

thank  you 
       [image]

Comment: That's weird, I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: Check your normals.

Comment: Check that you don't have duplicates of the doors/hood with e.g. the wrong material. If that's not it, is it possible you could [upload your .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599)? Try deleting everything except one of the affected objects, if the problem persists please upload just that (we don't need the whole car, just the problem)